# How can I make Infinite Scroll using Firebase Realtime Database - v9

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: DB Structure]

I want to make a Infinite scroll to load only 2 users data at first, then when admin will click on Load More button, it should load next 2 user data. Is it possible in Realtime Database?
Similarly, I can use this to display users their post to limited numbers if they have many posts in the database instead to loading all the posts at once.

I tried it by using orderByChild() method, but it doesn't work as expected. I am beginner in Firebase.

Edit: Thank you Jay for guiding me.
Here is json database structure:

```
{
  "users": {
    "BZh9dyH3fMTqoKFIOb38Px0ha243": {
      "info": {
        "private": {
          "displayName": "John",
          "email": "john@gmail.com",
          "emailVerified": true,
          "isAnonymous": false,
          "metadata": {
            "createdAt": 1661687731596,
            "lastLoginAt": 1669986823839
          },
          "photoURL": "https://...profile.png"
        },
        "public": {
          "displayName": "John",
          "photoURL": "https://...profile.png"
        }
      }
    },
    "RpxBOI7jXHef5NyEFFaI29ZMXcw2": {
      "info": {
        "private": {
          "displayName": "Albert",
          "email": "albert@gmail.com",
          "emailVerified": true,
          "isAnonymous": false,
          "metadata": {
            "createdAt": 166168790988,
            "lastLoginAt": 1669986823839
          },
          "photoURL": "https://...profile.png"
        },
        "public": {
          "displayName": "Albert",
          "photoURL": "https://...profile.png"
        }
      }
      // more users...
    }
  }
}
```

Code I have tried:

```
let last = 0;
let getNextData = () => {
  let dataRef = last === 0 ? query(ref(db, 'users'), orderByChild("info/private/metadata/createdAt"), limitToFirst(2)) : query(ref(db, 'users'), orderByChild("info/private/metadata/createdAt"), limitToFirst(2), startAfter(last));
    
  get(dataRef).then((snapshot) => {
    last += snapshot.size
  })
}
// load first two users
getNextData()
// load more
gId("loadMore").addEventListener("click", () => getNextData())
```

But it loads only 2 users every time.

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted.  To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). We are not a code writing service but can help with existing code. Please include the code you've attempted in the question